# Javascript save one member's value as another member's child object (key value pair)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of object in which I want to store the value of some values from the siblings

```js
let widgets = [{
  bgColor: "bg_white",
  config: undefined,
  id: 337,
  name: "Test",
  sizeLarge: "l26",
  sizeMedium: "m23",
  sizeSmall: "s23",
},
 {
  bgColor: "bg_red",
  config: undefined,
  id: 338,
  name: "Test 1",
  sizeLarge: "l25",
  sizeMedium: "m24",
  sizeSmall: "s24",
}];

const dict = ['bgColor', 'sizeLarge', 'sizeMedium', 'sizeSmall', 'name'];
 widgets = widgets.map(obj => { 
          const keys = Object.keys(obj);
          for (let key of dict) {
            //Object.assign(obj.config, {[key]: obj[key]});
             obj.config = {
               [key]: obj[key],
            }
          }
            return obj;
    });
 console.log(widgets);
```

I want to have all the key values inside the "**dict**" array to be inside the config for each object. But only the last value ("**name**") is added. If I do **Object.assign** I get *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"* error. How do I achieve the below expected result. TS solutions also accepted.

PS: **config** should be **undefined** initially

This is the expected result

```js
let results = [{
  bgColor: "bg_white",
  config: {
    name: "Test",
    sizeLarge: "l26",
    sizeMedium: "m23",
    sizeSmall: "s23",
  },
  id: 337,
  name: "Test",
  sizeLarge: "l26",
  sizeMedium: "m23",
  sizeSmall: "s23",
},
 {
  bgColor: "bg_red",
  config: {
    name: "Test 1",
    sizeLarge: "l25",
    sizeMedium: "m24",
    sizeSmall: "s24",
  },
  id: 338,
  name: "Test 1",
  sizeLarge: "l25",
  sizeMedium: "m24",
  sizeSmall: "s24",
}];
```

Comment: `widgets.map(obj => ({...obj, config:dict.reduce((acc,curr) => ({...acc,[curr]:obj[curr]}),{})}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign empty object to your `config` in the loop and then assign is property something like

```js
let widgets = [{
  bgColor: "bg_white",
  config: undefined,
  id: 337,
  name: "Test",
  sizeLarge: "l26",
  sizeMedium: "m23",
  sizeSmall: "s23",
},
 {
  bgColor: "bg_red",
  config: undefined,
  id: 338,
  name: "Test 1",
  sizeLarge: "l25",
  sizeMedium: "m24",
  sizeSmall: "s24",
}];

const dict = ['bgColor', 'sizeLarge', 'sizeMedium', 'sizeSmall', 'name'];
 widgets = widgets.map(obj => { 
          const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k=> k != 'config');
          obj.config={};
          for (let key of keys) {
             obj.config[key] = obj[key];
          }
            return obj;
    });
 console.log(widgets);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` to get all the key-value pairs corresponding to keys in the array, then use `Object.fromEntries` to create an object from it.

```js
let widgets = [{
  bgColor: "bg_white",
  config: undefined,
  id: 337,
  name: "Test",
  sizeLarge: "l26",
  sizeMedium: "m23",
  sizeSmall: "s23",
},
 {
  bgColor: "bg_red",
  config: undefined,
  id: 338,
  name: "Test 1",
  sizeLarge: "l25",
  sizeMedium: "m24",
  sizeSmall: "s24",
}];
const dict = ['bgColor', 'sizeLarge', 'sizeMedium', 'sizeSmall', 'name'];
let res = widgets.map(o => ({...o, config: Object.fromEntries(dict.map(k => [k, o[k]]))}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: can it be es2018 solution please

Comment: @Viira You can polyfill `Object.fromEntries` or use `widgets.map(o => ({...o, config: dict.reduce((acc,k)=>(acc[k]=o[k],acc),{})}));`

Answer (score 0):

You could map the objects and build a new object for `config`.

```js
const
    widgets = [{ bgColor: "bg_white", config: undefined, id: 337, name: "Test", sizeLarge: "l26", sizeMedium: "m23", sizeSmall: "s23" }, { bgColor: "bg_red", config: undefined, id: 338, name: "Test 1", sizeLarge: "l25", sizeMedium: "m24", sizeSmall: "s24" }],
    dict = ['bgColor', 'sizeLarge', 'sizeMedium', 'sizeSmall', 'name'],
    result = widgets.map(o => ({
        ...o,
        config: Object.fromEntries(dict.map(k => [k, o[k]]))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to mutate the given array, you could just add the wanted properties directly.

```js
const
    widgets = [{ bgColor: "bg_white", config: undefined, id: 337, name: "Test", sizeLarge: "l26", sizeMedium: "m23", sizeSmall: "s23" }, { bgColor: "bg_red", config: undefined, id: 338, name: "Test 1", sizeLarge: "l25", sizeMedium: "m24", sizeSmall: "s24" }],
    dict = ['bgColor', 'sizeLarge', 'sizeMedium', 'sizeSmall', 'name'];

widgets.forEach(o => {
    o.config = {};
    for (const k of dict) o.config[k] = o[k];
});

console.log(widgets);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can it be es2018 solution please

Answer (score 0):

You're currently overwriting the `config` object in each iteration of the loop with a new object that only contains one property. Instead, you need to create the `config` object outside of the loop and add each property to it.

```
widgets = widgets.map(obj => { 
  const config = {};
  for (let key of dict) {
    config[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return { ...obj, config };
});
```